# Disable Button until all edittext fields are not empty and the logic fulfilled

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a problem where I need to disable the button until all the `edittext` fields have valid data in them and not empty. I would also want to have the submit `button` not enabled if there is any null or empty field.

Part of my logic includes for example that the user's first and second name should at least have 3 characters as shown.

I am able to validate all the edittext fields using TextWatcher afterTextChanged method but I unable to disable the button until all the data is valid.

My question is how do I make sure I disable my button until all the logic is validated?

Below is my code.

```
 @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) { 

email.addTextChangedListener(new EditTextWatcher(email));
            password.addTextChangedListener(new EditTextWatcher(password));
            name.addTextChangedListener(new EditTextWatcher(name));

 button.setOnClickListener((View v) -> {
                updateDatabase();
            }

            }

private class EditTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

        private View view;

        private EditTextWatcher(View view) {
            this.view = view;
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.email:
                    validateEmail();
                    break;
                case R.id.password:
                    validatePassword();
                    break;

            }

        }
        }

        private boolean validateEmail() {
            String email = email.getText().toString().trim();

            if (email.isEmpty() || !isValidEmail(email)) {
                layoutEmail.setError(getString(R.string.err_msg_email));
                requestFocus(email);
                return false;
            } else {
                layoutEmail.setErrorEnabled(false);
            }
            return true;
        }

        private static boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
            return !TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
        }

     private boolean validatePassword() {
            String password = password.getText().toString().trim();
            if (StringUtils.isEmpty(password) || !isValidPassword(password)) {
                layoutPassword.setError(getString(R.string.err_msg_password));
                requestFocus(password);
                return false;
            } else {
                password.setErrorEnabled(false);
            }
            return true;
        }

            private void requestFocus(View view) {
            if (view.requestFocus()) {
                getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
            }
        }

            private boolean validatePassword() {
            String password = password .getText().toString().trim();
            if (StringUtils.isEmpty(password) || !isValidPassword(password)) {
                layoutPassword.setError(getString(R.string.err_msg_password));
                requestFocus(password);
                return false;
            } else {
                layoutPassword.setErrorEnabled(false);
            }
            return true;
        }

            private static boolean isValidPassword(String password){
            return !TextUtils.isEmpty(password) && PASSWORD_PATTERN.matcher(password).matches();
        }
```

Comment: You're more likely to get a helpful answer if you can reduce the code to just what's needed to show the problem.

Comment: You can achieve that with [Data Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding)

Answer (score 2):

Disable your button in xml and enable after completion of your logic

call this below method in afterTextChanged irrespctive of viewId

`````
void validatationForButton(){
   if(validateEmail()&&validatePassWord()){
      //enable Button here
      btn.setEnabled(true);
}}````
`````

Comment: I have tried enabling the button in the afterTextChanged method but it did not help. Where would I enable the button?

Comment: @Programmer254 check the above modified answer

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Works like a charm! Upvoted!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should implement `enable/disable` button within `onTextChange()`.

```
      @Override 
      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (!s.toString().isEmpty() && s.toString().length() > 0) {
          // enable the button here
        } else {
          // disable the button here
        }
      }
```

Because every time you type in `TextFiled` or every text change occur, the button will be enabled or disabled.

Comment: Tried this earlier but it did not work. @Bhaskar Pasupula answer works!